# Changing Size of Image

Tags: pygame

I'm trying to put a picture in my python game, so far I have this:

```
picture = pygame.image.load(picture.jpg)
screen.fill(BLACK)
screen.blit(picture, (0,0))
```

This successfully adds the picture, but takes up the whole screen. Is it possible to reduce the size of this picture?
Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you can scale an image with transform.scale.

`picture = pygame.transform.scale(picture, (1280, 720))`

Also have you tried playing around with the parameters in screen.blit? 
I think instead of passing a point into the "Dest" parameter you can pass a rectangle.

`screen.blit(picture), (0,0,width,height))`

Comment: The `rect` argument in `blit` doesn't resize the picture, it draws a piece of the picture.  The `scale` function is probably what the OP is looking for.